# citrix branch repeater performance monitoring

Tags: branch, snmp, citrix

I am developing  citrix branch repeater  for performance monitoring through the snmp oid
in which what is mean by Icasentrate measure and is it cumulative measure or not, and what is unit of that.can u please any one suggest related that.

Answer (score 0):

Branch Repeater/Cloud Bridge can be monitored using SNMP.

See http://www.citrixmonitor.com